# Isomorphisms on $L^p$ and on $l^p$?

Tags: functional-analysis

I want to prove that $l^p$ is isomorphic to the infinite dierct sum of $l^p$, similarly for $L^p$. Every time I try to define an operator, I lose one of the properties that this operators must have like surjectivity or linearity ! 
Can you help me please !

Comment: What topology do you want on the infinite direct sum? Or are you talking about isomorphism as vector spaces, without regard to topologies?

Comment: The infinite direct product is not separable, @julien.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Sure, good point. What are talking about, here? I always find this terminology confusing. Is it the $C_0$ sum?

Comment: In our case we want the $ ||(x_n)||$ to be finite, were each coordinate of $(x_n)$ is an elements in $lp$, which means that the sequence of real numbers $(||x_n||)$ must belong to $lp$

Answer (score 3):

For $\ell_p$, you want to consider breaking up the index set (presumably ${\mathbb N} = \{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ as the union of infinitely many infinite sets.  For example, take a $2$-dimensional grid
$$ \pmatrix{ 1 &2 &4 & 7 & \ldots \cr
             3 &5 &8 & 12 & \ldots \cr
             6 &9 &13 & 18 & \ldots \cr
             10 & 14 & 19 & 25 & \ldots \cr
             \ldots &\ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots \cr}$$

and use the rows.  Then $\ell_p$ is the infinite direct sum of copies of $\ell_p$ with the $p$-norm $\|(X_1, X_2, \ldots )\|_p = \left( \sum_i \|X_i\|_p \right)^p$, such that
$X = (x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots)$ corresponds to $(X_1, X_2, X_3, \ldots)$ with
$X_1 = (x_1, x_2, x_4, x_7, \ldots)$, $X_2 = (x_3, x_5, x_8, x_{12})$, ....

Similarly, for $L_p([0,1])$, break up the interval into countably many subintervals, say 
$I_k = [a_k, a_{k+1}]$ where $a_n$ is an increasing sequence with $a_1 = 0$
and $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 1$.